# Unity, injecting instances to controller gives seemingly unrelated exception

Tags: c#, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5.1

This is what i want to be able to do (passing interface(s) to Controllers):

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(ITestService service)
    {
        var test = new TestModel();
        test.Greeting = "yo" + service.GetString();
        test.Name = "nils";

        return View(test);

    }
}
```

This is what i have put in Global.asax.cs in the Application_Start() to try to make that work:

```
        // Create a new Unity dependency injection container
        var unity = new UnityContainer();


        unity.RegisterType<ITestService,TestService>();

        // Finally, override the default dependency resolver with Unity
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new IoCContainer(unity));
```

I have also, as you can see, created an IoCContainer class which looks as follows:

```
public class IoCContainer : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    public IoCContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);

        return null;

    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (_container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);

        return new List<object>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When i try to access the `"http://humptidumptiurl/Test"` it tells me:

```
A public action method 'Login' was not found on controller 'Companyname.Product.Web.Controllers.TestController'.
```

Now... i thought it should resolve the ITestService.. not bother about a completely different Controller? other controllers that does not use Unity yet, work as they have always done....

Inputs on how i could achieve my desired solution would be greatly appriciated

**EDIT:**

Thank you! Of course it injects through the constructor... I should have thought of that... but now it gives me this error message:

```
{"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Stimline.Xplorer.Web.Controllers.TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}
```

Edited testController:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public TestController(ITestService service)
    {
        _testService = service;
    }

    // GET: Test
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var test = new TestModel();
        test.Greeting = "yo" + _testService.GetString();
        test.Name = "nils";

        return View(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the default action on your route setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're injecting your dependency into your action method.

When using `IDependencyResolver` in this manner you tend to inject dependencies into your constructor.

Try changing controller to look something like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestService service;

    public TestController(ITestService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // GET: Test
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var test = new TestModel();
        test.Greeting = "yo";
        test.Name = "nils";

        // TODO do something with ITestService
        // this.service.DoSomethingCool()

        return View(test);
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much... foolish of me... :p 

{"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Company.Product.Web.Controllers.TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}

Would you know the reason for this too?

Comment: Sure - your `IDependencyResolver` implementation only returns an instance when a type is registered in your container. You `TestController` does not exist in the container so it returns null. It therefore doesn't know how to instantiate it. You can use the [Unity MVC Integration](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/1.4.0) on NuGet instead which implements this correctly.

Comment: Well.. first off if i browse the containerobject i can find The ITestService and the TestService and they are mapped to eachother....

Second i tried installing the Unity.MVC5, and the UnityConfig of the UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); does not resolve....

Comment: Looks like the NuGet package adds a `UnityConfig.cs` into the `App_Start` folder of your project. Move you registrations into that file and make sure you have the relevant using statements at the top of `Global.asax.cs`. [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is your friend here :)

Comment: Yes! :) now it resolves and initalizes the service correctly... however now i am back to the first error message, where it cant find the logon method.... 'sigh'.. if you still have inputs i will be eternally greatful... but since the scope of the question is no longer valid i guess you are not obligated to ;)

Comment: Not sure how your routes are configured but you don't have an action called Login in your TestController...

Comment: hehe.. i know... it's driving me mad.. i guess i'll have to check out the Routes when i get to work tomorrow... Thanks for all your help, it is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare it like this :

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {

        private ITestService service;
        public TestController(ITestService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        // GET: Test
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = new TestModel();
            test.Greeting = "yo";
            test.Name = "nils";

            return View(test);
        }
    }
```

Please inject your dependencies inside your constructor. You by mistake passed it to your action method.